# Webpack bundle not exporting React Component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle

I am building a frontend package that will export out 1 React component for other packages to import and render. I am trying to use webpack to bundle my React component however I can't seem to get my component to be exported from the bundle.

I am testing the bundle by importing the `dist/bundle` directly into a storybook story to render out.

Here is a naive example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// index.js

import React from "react";

export const ComponentToExport = () => <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
```

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/index.js",

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // transpile with babel
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I then run `webpack --mode development` which produces the bundle, `dist/bundle.js`.

I have a story in storybook I'm trying to import the bundle from dist and render it:

```
// app.stories.js

import React from "react";
import { ComponentToExport } from "../dist/bundle.js";
console.log("ComponentToExport: ", ComponentToExport);

export default { title: "RemoteComponentExample" };

export const example = () => (<ComponentToExport />);
```

I expect a story with "Hello World" to be printed on the page however I am seeing this error:

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

[image]

Also in the `console.log(ComponentToExport)` statement in my story, I am getting `undefined` returned in my dev tools.

I don't believe the component is being exported from `dist/bundle.js`. I've tried changing the `libraryTarget` in the webpack config along with adding/removing some other options however nothing seems to work.

What should be changed in my webpack config so that the bundle properly exports the `ComponentToExport` component so it can be imported in other files, and eventually consumed by other packages?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @DanMad I never did. I ended up moving on from this issue, but still don't have a definitive resolution.